# NOT able to SET value passed in <apex:param> to APEX CONTROLLER

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-param

**VF PAGE**

```
<!--Here Custom_Field__c is a PickList ON task Object  -->

<apex:inputField id="abc" value="{!wrapTemp.task.Custom_Field__c}" > 

    <!--Here fieldselected is a APEX method being called onchange of picklist values of input 
     rerender the pageBlock -->
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!fieldselected}" event="onchange" rerender="editBlock">
    
    <!-- We are able to SEE this value when we select Picklist value -->
                {!wrapTemp.task.Custom_Field__c}
                
    <!-- the field is NOT being populated with the selected Picklist Value which is coming above-->
    <apex:param name="field" value="{!wrapTemp.task.Custom_Field__c}" assignTo="{!field}"/>
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputField>
```

**APEX CONTROLLER**

```
public with sharing class testController{

    public String field {get; set;}
    
    public static void fieldselected()
    {
        // Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('field') this is coming blank
        System.debug('Field value >> '+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('field'));
        // field is coming blank
        system.debug('field >> '+field);
    }
    
}
```